# how to tangle only source code blocks that belong to a specific target file?

Tags: org-babel, tangle

Let's say we have the following org file:

```
#+begin_src python :tangle "target1.py"
a=11
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle "target2.py"
a=21
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle "target1.py"
b=12
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle "target3.py"
a=31
#+end_src
```

Now, I want to tangle only those source blocks that are
meant to be tangled to `target1.py` and filter out those ones that are meant
to be tangled to the other files.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270142/how-to-tangle-source-code-blocks-that-belong-to-a-specific-target-file) answer one should use:

```
(org-babel-tangle-file "myfile.org" "target1.py")
```

The problem is that this command does not work as required.
It tangles **all** the source blocks and creates all three files,
not just `target1.py`. What is interesting, filtering out by language (third parameter of `org-babel-tangle-file`) works as expected.

I'm using `emacs 29.1` and `org-mode 9.6.1` and `org-babel-tangle-file` in my `ob-tangle.el` looks like this:

```
(defun org-babel-tangle-file (file &optional target-file lang-re)
 "Extract the bodies of source code blocks in FILE.
  Source code blocks are extracted with `org-babel-tangle'.

  Optional argument TARGET-FILE can be used to specify a default
  export file for all source blocks.

  Optional argument LANG-RE can be used to limit the exported
  source code blocks by languages matching a regular expression.

  Return list of the tangled file names."
  (interactive "fFile to tangle: \nP")
    (let* ((visited (find-buffer-visiting file))
      (buffer (or visited (find-file-noselect file))))
   (prog1
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (mapcar #'expand-file-name
               (org-babel-tangle nil target-file lang-re))))
       (unless visited (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found in the docstring of `org-babel-tangle`, it says

```
When two universal prefix arguments, only tangle blocks for the
tangle file of the block at point.
```

So you should just place the cursor on one of the blocks for the correct target file, then do `C-u C-u M-x` `org-babel-tangle`.

EDIT in response to the comment

For the 'programmatic' case, I think there is no 'out of the box' solution.
However, in that case, you can simply tweak the `org-babel-tangle` code, to achieve what you want (alternatively, as mentioned in the comments by @NickD, you could programmatically 'mimic' the interactive solution above)

From the file buffer you can use this slightly modified version of `org-babel-tangle` (the code looks long, but I really only quickly removed a few 'conditionals' from the original function)

```lisp
(defun my-tangle (tangle-file)
  (interactive "P")
  (run-hooks 'org-babel-pre-tangle-hook)
  ;; Possibly Restrict the buffer to the current code block
  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion
      (let ((block-counter 0)
        (org-babel-default-header-args org-babel-default-header-args)
        path-collector)
    (mapc ;; map over file-names
     (lambda (by-fn)
       (let ((file-name (car by-fn)))
         (when file-name
               (let ((lspecs (cdr by-fn))
             (fnd (file-name-directory file-name))
             modes make-dir she-banged lang)
             ;; drop source-blocks to file
             ;; We avoid append-to-file as it does not work with tramp.
             (with-temp-buffer
           (mapc
            (lambda (lspec)
              (let* ((block-lang (car lspec))
                 (spec (cdr lspec))
                 (get-spec (lambda (name) (cdr (assq name (nth 4 spec)))))
                 (she-bang (let ((sheb (funcall get-spec :shebang)))
                         (when (> (length sheb) 0) sheb)))
                 (tangle-mode (funcall get-spec :tangle-mode)))
                (unless (string-equal block-lang lang)
              (setq lang block-lang)
              (let ((lang-f (org-src-get-lang-mode lang)))
                (when (fboundp lang-f) (ignore-errors (funcall lang-f)))))
                ;; if file contains she-bangs, then make it executable
                (when she-bang
              (unless tangle-mode (setq tangle-mode #o755)))
                (when tangle-mode
              (add-to-list 'modes (org-babel-interpret-file-mode tangle-mode)))
                ;; Possibly create the parent directories for file.
                (let ((m (funcall get-spec :mkdirp)))
              (and m fnd (not (string= m "no"))
                   (setq make-dir t)))
                ;; Handle :padlines unless first line in file
                (unless (or (string= "no" (funcall get-spec :padline))
                    (= (point) (point-min)))
              (insert "\n"))
                (when (and she-bang (not she-banged))
              (insert (concat she-bang "\n"))
              (setq she-banged t))
                (org-babel-spec-to-string spec)
                (setq block-counter (+ 1 block-counter))))
            lspecs)
           (when make-dir
             (make-directory fnd 'parents))
                   (unless
                       (and (file-exists-p file-name)
                            (let ((tangle-buf (current-buffer)))
                              (with-temp-buffer
                                (insert-file-contents file-name)
                                (and
                                 (equal (buffer-size)
                                        (buffer-size tangle-buf))
                                 (= 0
                                    (let (case-fold-search)
                                      (compare-buffer-substrings
                                       nil nil nil
                                       tangle-buf nil nil)))))))
                     ;; erase previous file
                     (when (file-exists-p file-name)
                       (delete-file file-name))
             (write-region nil nil file-name)
             (mapc (lambda (mode) (set-file-modes file-name mode)) modes))
                   (push file-name path-collector))))))
       (org-babel-tangle-collect-blocks nil tangle-file))
    (message "Tangled %d code block%s from %s" block-counter
         (if (= block-counter 1) "" "s")
         (file-name-nondirectory
          (buffer-file-name
           (or (buffer-base-buffer)
                       (current-buffer)
                       (and (org-src-edit-buffer-p)
                            (org-src-source-buffer))))))
    ;; run `org-babel-post-tangle-hook' in all tangled files
    (when org-babel-post-tangle-hook
      (mapc
       (lambda (file)
         (org-babel-with-temp-filebuffer file
           (run-hooks 'org-babel-post-tangle-hook)))
       path-collector))
        (run-hooks 'org-babel-tangle-finished-hook)
    path-collector))))
```

If you would like to use the `org-babel-tangle-file` version, then you can additionally tweak that function to use the modified function defined above (here again I only changed one line of the original function)

```lisp
(defun my-tangle-file (file target-file)
  (interactive "fFile to tangle: \nP")
  (let* ((visited (find-buffer-visiting file))
         (buffer (or visited (find-file-noselect file))))
    (prog1
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          (org-with-wide-buffer
           (mapcar #'expand-file-name
                   (my-tangle target-file))))
      (unless visited (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

After evaluating the above functions you can use it as follows

```
(org-babel-tangle-file "myfile.org" "target1.py")
```

END EDIT

Comment: OK. But what if I want to do it programmatically? I'd like to have a function for that - something like (my/org-babel-tangle-file "myfile.org" "target1.py"). Do I need to open source file, search for appropriate source block and then invoke the command you mentioned? Couldn't it be achieved simpler?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer

Comment: The call just before the `END EDIT` should be `(my-tangle-file ...)`, right? Or did you mean to override `org-babel-tangle-file`? BTW, although I looked for something simpler, I was not able to come up with anything, but in the process I looked through the `org-babel-tangle-*` API and it looks to me as if it's in need of serious refactoring - does it look that way to you?

Comment: I also wondered if the `C-u C-u org-babel-tangle` solution could be used in the programmatic case by going to an appropriate src block (presumably within a `save-excursion`) and then doing a `call-interactively` on `org-bable-tangle` with a `'(16)` arg. But I did not actually try it out to see whether it would work and whether it would be any simpler.

Comment: Yeah I had that option in mind also, and I guess that should work also indeed. But I thought this was 'simpler' (or equally simple); I really only quickly changed (i.e. mainly removed) a few lines. I prefer 'less code solutions' also, but I would call the other solution a more 'hacky' solution. Nothing wrong with a good working hacky solution of course :) You could add the other solution also, it should be only a few lines indeed. And it would be a valid and 'informative' answer also.

Comment: @NickD Using `call-interactively` with a `'(16)` argument was the idea I also had in my mind when writing the first comment but I'm still too poor at elisp programming to write the function in less than a couple of days...  I'll try to implement this approach in my free time and post it then. As for now, dalanicolai's code does the job. Thanks.

Comment: @martinoidar To complete your exercise, let me offer some suggestions (things that I would probably use): use `while` with  `org-next-block`, stop either when matching a regexp (for the :tangle filename), or use `org-babel-get-src-block-info`. Then, instead of using the `save-excursion`, have a look at the code of `org-babel-tangle-file`. To learn `elisp` the built-in [Emacs Lisp Intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/) is good (probably the best place to start).

Answer (score 0):

Horribly hacky idea, may or may not work for your use case: symlink `target2.py` and `target3.py` to `/dev/null` before you call `org-babel-tangle`.  Obviously you have to remember (or automate) to remove those symlinks afterwards.

I know, I should be ashamed of myself.